# "It is about time I had a family" - Is this sentence grammatically correct?

Tags: grammaticality, phrases

Recently, I stumbled over a sentence that read: "I am 30. It is about time I had a family of my own". Is it grammatically correct?

Shouldn't the correct sentence be "I am 30. It is about time I should have a family of my own"

Comment: Perhaps [edit] the question to let us know why you believe the word "should" should be included?

Comment: _Be (about) time_ is an idiom that can take a tensed _that_ complement, as here: _It's about time (that) I started a famiy_ or and infinitive: _It's about time (for me) to start a family_. The tense in a _that_ clause is past, because this is counterfactual; _be (about) time_ always refers to an event or activity in the future, which has not yet happened. (There may even be some here who would say this is `Subjunctive`. It takes all kinds.)

Comment: @MattGutting Because I think this is probably the right expression to use (If I am not wrong):)

Comment: @sourav And it's right because...?

Comment: Well.. I am not sure @MattGutting 
Will you please help me to understand these? :)

Comment: @JohnLawler I am still trying to understand what you have said.

Comment: About all that sounds "odd" from the original is the use of "it is" instead of "it's".

Comment: The grammatical difference here is that *"I had"* is the subjunctive (also called the irrealis to distinguish it from the mandative subjunctive) and *"I should have"* is the modal equivalent of the irrealis. Both are correct. They mean the same thing. There may be regional differences as to whether one is more common than the other.

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/603360/2085).

Answer (score 2):

[Subjunctive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subjunctive_mood) forms of verbs are typically used to express various states of unreality such as wish, emotion, possibility, judgment, opinion, necessity, or action that has not yet occurred.

In Latin, there are grammatical forms defined for each in a list of perceived different subjunctive moods. However, in English, where our grammar is not as complex as Latin, the subjunctive is more about usage, and how that usage projects, proposes or imagines the story to be told.

Frequently, we borrow from the past and past perfect tenses to denote subjunctive, because English does not have a set of tenses dedicated to the subjunctive.

- You don't believe me. You **should** believe me. **Should** you believe me, I **would** reward you with eternal life.
- I am not a god. It is impossible that I am a god. If I **were** a god, I **would** create a whole universe of blueberry cheesecake.
- My womb is broken. I can't have a baby. If I **had** a baby, I **would** sing hallelujah all my life.
- I believe miracles **should** happen to me. I have been praying for a miracle. It is time the miracle **happened**. It is time I **had** a baby, but I still have not had a baby. It is time I **had** a whole family of children of my womb.
- This meeting has over-run its schedule. I am hungry. It's time we **ate** lunch.